# TikiWiki user management

Tags: admin, tiki-wiki

How do I manage users of our tikiwiki?

The tiki process on the server is ran under my name.  I am the user of the tikiwiki, but I am not sure I am an admin user.
Most likely not but question one is:  How do I find that out?
(my Admin Menu is empty)
Some user contacted me saying her account is "Locked".  It so happened that there is no one else to restore it, but me.
Can anyone help where to look?  I only used my tikiwiki account to limited extent.  Just wrote couple of articles.  But never administered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a built in user in Tiki called "admin" and that is in a group called "Admins" which has permission to do everything, so it sounds like your user isn't in that group.

If the admin user was set up with a valid email account (and you know it and have access to it) then you can get the password reset and a link to make a new one will be emailed to that address. If you can access the installer or the database then there are various other options on how to recover the admin login here: https://doc.tiki.org/Lost+admin+password

Once you have done this and can administer the Tiki again you should add your usual user to the Admins group.

To unlock another user's account you will need to either access the user admin list (once you have admin login again) or if you can get to the database you should be able to clear the relevant field in the database directly using phpmyadmin or similar as a last resort (ask again if you need this much detail).

Comment: The problem is, that initially I was just a user of the tiki.  Then, the person administering it, left the company and, I "inherited" being have to be the one to be logged in to the server machine - so all the process there run.  However, my own tiki-wiki account was never altered to give me any admin rights, or anything.  I do NOT know, the "valid" email for the "admin" user, if any.  :(

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I have found the user/password for admin account and can manage things from there.